# Move child folder content to an Amazon S3 bucket using AWS Code Deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy

I have created the below-mentioned pipeline in AWS.

CodeCommit -> CodeBuild -> CodeDeploy

I am using `ng serve` command to build the Angular JS source code and it creates a folder named `dist` and moves all the build content.

When deploying the build result to an Amazon S3 bucket, is it possible to move only the content inside the `dist` folder?

At the moment, all the source files are being transferred to the Amazon S3 bucket with the `dist` folder.

Other than writing a Lambda function to achieve this, is there a shortcut to achieve this within the pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder why you have used CodeDeploy for S3 copying. You can achieve the same using CodeBuild itself.

```
CodeCommit => CodePipeline => CodeBuild => S3
```

After creating the `build (dist)`, add commands for S3 sync in your buildspec.yml file

Sample few lines of `buildspec.yml` for your use case.

```
- ng serve
- ls -ltr
- cd dist
- aws s3 sync . s3://YOUR_BUCKET --acl bucket-owner-full-control
```